# Uploading big files doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, file-upload, php

I'm curently using PHP for uploading images to my server. But -obviously- there's a limit in filesize, and I can't modify the .htaccess file, and can't access the php.ini file..

What happens when I, for example, add:

**php_value post_max_size 10100000**
, and:

**php_value upload_max_filesize 10000000**

to the .htaccess file, I get error 500.. This error will stay until I put back the original .htaccess file..

Neither does making a new php.ini in my main folder, or using ini_set() in php help, so my question is: is there a way to upload bigger files without having to alter php.ini or .htaccess ?

thanks in advance,
Jeroen

Comment: Sure, just don't use PHP. If you can't modify the PHP settings, then you'll have to use something other than PHP, or upload the file in multiple smaller chunks and then reassemble on the server.

Comment: Check your Apache's error log -- it should contain exact description for the 500 error.

Comment: ok.. I figured out that upload_max_filesize is "12M" by standard.. So that shouldn't be the problem.. I now see that it might be the memory limit.. I upload and resize images. I guess that's sucking up all the memory, as the page in which I perform the resize functions is not fully loaded..

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change those directives, there is not much you can do.

Maybe you could use some other language than PHP, for your upload components ?

Maybe a CGI written in Perl, for example -- there are still hosting services supporting those ; and they might not have the same limitations.

Answer (score 0):

this is out of 32bit Linuy limit.

Try using

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1500M
php_value post_max_size 1500M
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out what to do. I cannot use CGI or PERL on my host, so I got to stick to PHP, and thus I'm left with this memory_limit.. I don't know if ini_set() is enabled on my server, so I need to find a way not to overload the memory dedicated to each request..

What I'm planning to do, is giving every upload (and resize) request a new, fresh page.. So each upload will have it's own iframe!!

This worked in Chrome so far, will test it later for other browsers, as I don't know if post requests will be accepted for iframes in every browser..

Comment: I'm stuck here.. The upload won't work yet in FF and IE. I checked the filename being passed in the $_FILES-array, and it seems like the file is not uploaded in the iframe with IE and FF..